# Add Modified by and Date Modified to Custom App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, custom-list, modified

I created a custom Sharepoint app which our business uses to track projects.  I'd like to add to columns to one of the tables, one for last modified and one for last modified by (that will show who changed it last based on login).  I figured this would be simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Every SharePoint list includes `CreatedBy`, `Created`, `Modified`, and `ModifiedBy` fields by default -- because they are part of the base `Item` content type. They perform precisely the behavior you're describing.

If you are looking to access them from any of the client APIs the user entities are named `Author` and `Editor` respectively, but the date fields are still called `Modified` and `Created`

If you're using the REST API you'll have to do something like `$select=Editor/Title&$expand=Editor`

The CSOM APIs will bring back those values automatically with a request for list items, you just have to use something like `item.get_item("Editor").get_lookupValue()` to get the users name (note this is a JS Example, although the C# version would be very similar)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.  I am using the Sharepoint "Sites" that came with my Office 365 subscription.  I created a new "app" which I can then access to edit via MS Access.  I'm not sure what you are referring to related to an API, etc...  It seems all I may need to do is add the correct code to a column that I add to the table?  Sorry in advance if I seem confused, I am, and this is my first experience with Sharepoint.  Thanks!

Comment: Aha! Boy that changes things... let me do some research, but in the mean time you should change your question: did you create an 'Access Web App' or is it a list that you manage with the Access desktop program?

Comment: I crated an Access Web App via Sharepoint Online (sites via Office 365).  Thank you!